# how to loop through a specified range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database of movies where one field is the year which it was released.

I want to create a query which will loop through each decade and will calculate the sum of a particular field for that decade. I have no idea how I can get a loop for every decade. Can anyone help?

Comment: I did a similar query in postgresql. Gonna check if I have I saved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the decades where you don't have any movies as well as those with movies, then you can use [`generate_series`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SERIES) to build you list of decades and the do a left outer join to your table; `generate_series` is the standard way to build numeric and time lists on the fly in PostgreSQL. Something like this should get you started:

```
select decade.d, count(t.year)
from generate_series(1900, 2100, 10) as decade(d)
left outer join your_table t on decade.d = floor(t.year / 10) * 10
group by decade.d
order by decade.d
```

That will produce output like this:

```
  d   | count 
------+-------
 1900 |     1
 1910 |     0
 1920 |     1
 1930 |     3
 1940 |     0
 1950 |     0
 1960 |     1
 1970 |     0
 1980 |     3
-- ...
 2100 |     0
```

You could adjust the first and last values for the `generate_series` call to match your data if desired.

The `floor(t.year / 10) * 10` bit gives you decade for a given year; it will convert 1942 to 1940, 2000 to 2000, etc.

You can set up a decade table (a one column table with one entry for each decade) if you move to a database that doesn't have something like `generate_series`. The SQL would be pretty much the same, just replace the `generate_series` call with your decade table.

Comment: While this might be irrelevant in this case, it is worth noticing that `generate_series` can also be used with date ranges.

Comment: @PeterM: Some care is needed when using `generate_series` with dates, that form of `generate_series` actually works with `timestampz`s and that can cause odd time zone problems if you're not careful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994322/479863

Comment: Thank you. Did not run into this issue, however added `timestamp` cast.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this(don't know how your tables look, guessing):

```
SELECT movie_year, sum(column_x)
FROM (
    SELECT year
        , date_trunc('decade', movie_year)::date as decade
        , column_x
    FROM movies) as movies_with_decades
GROUP BY decade
ORDER BY decade;
```