# Date Subtraction on PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

`I have a table (workers) which has a startdate column(s_date) representing when employee started working. So i want to create a trigger that if it's less than a year (365 days) of working, i m gonna give an exception. But something's wrong with the code. Any help_?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION control_func() RETURNS TRIGGER AS '
declare 
int1 integer;
tt  Date;
begin 
select now()::date into tt;
select s_date from workers; 
if(tt-s_date<365) then
RAISE EXCEPTION ''A message'';
end if;
RETURN NULL;
END;
' LANGUAGE  'plpgsql';
```

Comment: What's the error if there is? Shouldn't you do a `date_part` on now() and a_date?

Comment: @bonCodigo: The expression `now()::date` returns only the date. Using CURRENT_DATE is a better idea.

Comment: @Catcall: Using `current_date` also avoids [time zone problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994322/479863) that can arise when casting.

Comment: "Something's wrong with the code". **Always show your PostgreSQL version, your code, and the EXACT FULL TEXT OF ANY ERROR MESSAGES**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several problems. First of all, don't use single quotes to quote function bodies, that just makes a big mess, use [dollar quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) instead:

```
create or replace function f() returns trigger as $$
    ...
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Next, this doesn't do anything useful:

```
select s_date from workers;
```

That will try to grab all `s_date` values from `workers` and then throw them all away. You want to look at the current row for the trigger and that's available in [`NEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> `NEW`
>   Data type `RECORD`; variable holding the new database row for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` operations in row-level triggers. This variable is `NULL` in statement-level triggers and for `DELETE` operations.

So you can look at `new.s_date` to see the date you're interested in:

```
select now()::date into tt;
if tt - new.s_date < 365 then
    raise exception 'A message';
end if;
```

This is probably a row-level `before insert or update` trigger so you don't want `return null;` here; from the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/trigger-definition.html):

> A row-level trigger fired before an operation has the following choices:
>
> - It can return `NULL` to skip the operation for the current row. This instructs the executor to not perform the row-level operation that invoked the trigger (the insertion, modification, or deletion of a particular table row).
> - For row-level `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers only, the returned row becomes the row that will be inserted or will replace the row being updated. This allows the trigger function to modify the row being inserted or updated.

So your `return null;` means "skip this INSERT or UPDATE if the new record is valid" and that's not what you want. You want to `return new;`.

You also have an unused variable. And you can use [`current_date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) instead of your `tt`.

Your function should look more like this:

```
create or replace function control_func() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if current_date - new.s_date < 365 then
        raise exception 'A message'; 
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: the initial syntax is supposed to be `datediff`. However it is a MYSQL syntax. So you are better of with the above detailed and correct answer. ;-)

Ty this this in you code,
 Add another variable to save `s_date` say `ss`,

`If Datediff(days, tt, ss) < 365 then`

Comment: You don't need `date_part`, the difference between two `date`s in PostgreSQL is [the number of days between them](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#OPERATORS-DATETIME-TABLE).

Comment: @muistooshort I typed that from mobile and went off. The dictionary flips `datediff` into `date_part`. As you may have noticed it is clearly `Datediff` syntax further, I realized this is POSTGRES not MYSQL.... :-)