# Return list with dates within a specified range from a single query

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series, set-returning-functions

I'm trying to obtain a list of dates within  range, similar to the command NOW() in PostgreSQL, with the only difference that `now()`, returns only the current date.

If I execute it as follows I obtain:

```
select now();

2013-09-27 15:27:50.303-05
```

Or by example, I could do this:

```
select now() - interval '1' day;
```

and the result is yesterday

```
2013-09-27 15:27:50.303-05
```

What I need is a query that could return a list with every date within a given range, so if I provide 2013-09-20 and 2013-09-27 (I'm nor really interested in hours, only dates) I would like to obtain an output as follows:

```
2013-09-20
2013-09-21
2013-09-22
2013-09-23
2013-09-24
2013-09-25
2013-09-26
2013-09-27
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this? **By preference without using stored procedures or functions**, unless there is no other way ...

Comment: what is the point of this? just get now in your code and then make the list in your code rather then sql.

Comment: `generate_series( (now()-'1 week::interval)::date, now()::date)`

Comment: @Eluvatar: a possible use case is an outer join to be able to count things that "aren't there"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html)**, does *exactly* what you need:

```
SELECT generate_series('2013-09-20'::date
                     , '2013-09-27'::date
                     , interval '1 day')::date;
```

Takes two `timestamp` variables, but `dates` are also accepted.
Returns `timestamp with time zone`, so I cast to `date` according to your request.

A more verbose, but syntactically clearer version is to use the set returning function (SRF) as `FROM` item:

```
SELECT *
FROM   generate_series('2013-09-20'::date
                     , '2013-09-27'::date
                     , interval '1 day')::date;
```

Consider the comments below.

Comment: Using set returning functions in the select part is somewhat "deprecated". It's better to use them only in the `from` part.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Deprecated? Would you have a source for that? I'll offer a source to the contrary: `SELECT generate_subscripts('{NULL,1,NULL,2}'::int[], 1) AS s;` .. [direct quote from the current manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html#FUNCTIONS-SRF-SUBSCRIPTS)

Comment: Note exactly deprecated (that's why I put it in quotes) - but at least undocumented. There are discussions about this "feature" on the mailing list now and then, e.g. here: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Set-returning-functions-in-the-SELECT-list-tp5732422p5732446.html (that's about having more than one srf in the select list though)

Comment: Are there [hidden time zone problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12994322/479863) in those casts?

Comment: @muistooshort: No. Unlike the case you link to, my example uses consistent data types. Everything is computed according to local time zone, no corner case.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have found a [particularly interesting thread in pgsql-hackers dealing with the patch for the upcoming `WITH ORDINALITY`](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/e00d96898aa96955aab00ceec0d20c0e@news-out.riddles.org.uk#e00d96898aa96955aab00ceec0d20c0e@news-out.riddles.org.uk). It's also worth mentioning that [Function Calls in FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#AEN80759) are also *not* in the SQL standard.

Comment: Yes, I remember those. But still, having a SRF in the select list seems weird. It's like writing `select (select col from foo)` - which wouldn't be allowed